# Unable to obtain tokenresult oauthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken; unreachable network 69.171.229.24:443

Tags: networking, facebook-c#-sdk

I developed an FBConnect web application using C# .Net Framework 4.0 recently. Tested with my UAT server, everything just works fine, I'm able to login with my Facebook account, and perform all operation.

Unfortunately when I deploy the same code to my client's production environment, the FBConnect return "unreachable network 69.171.229.24:443". After several investigation, notice the port 443 is blocked! And due to corporate policy, this port is not allowed!!

Is there alternate way I can tweak my facebook app settings NOT to authenticate via port 443? instead of rewriting my code?

Please advice.

Comment: Ssl not allowed? Weird policy...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no alternative.

Port 443 is for secure HTTPS connections using TLS and SSL. Facebook, quite correctly, restricts access to their authentication mechanism to this port: (as far as I know) there are no alternative mechanisms that use a different port or an insecure login on port 80.

Check with your client to see if there's an proxy server that can be used for HTTPS connections.

Otherwise, request that your client opens that port.

Comment: Why would port 80 be open but port 443 be blocked? o_O